# Import 'Name' and 'Expected Return' list according to team name

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

Link:
https://www.sportsgambler.com/injuries/football/england-premier-league/

Test Fail (link in row `A2` and team name in `A1`):

`A1` = `Aston Villa`
`A2` = `https://www.sportsgambler.com/injuries/football/england-premier-league/`

```
=IMPORTXML(A2,"//h3[contains(@class,'"&A1&"')]//span[@class='inj-player'] | //h3[contains(@class,'"&A1&"')]//span[contains(@class,'inj-return')]")
```

But it returns with an error, in case I also need help to know how it would be the best way to import these two columns of data and divide them into two columns in the spreadsheet, because with the pure importxml you tried trying to know that the import will come all  the data in one column only.

Expected Result:

```
Emiliano Martinez            Doubtful
Jack Grealish                Early March
Matty Cash                   Mid March
Kortney Hause                Mid March
Wesley Moraes                Late March
```

Comment: I cannot understand about your goal. I apologize for this. Can you provide the detail of your result values you expect? And also, can you provide the sample value of the cell "A1"? Because I cannot understand about `team name`. I apologize for this again.

Comment: Done @Tanaike, thanks for support

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the following values.

  ```
    Emiliano Martinez            Doubtful
    Jack Grealish                Early March
    Matty Cash                   Mid March
    Kortney Hause                Mid March
    Wesley Moraes                Late March
  ```

When you want to use one `IMPORTXML`, in this case, how about the following sample formula?

#### Sample formula:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTXML(A2,"//div[./h3/a[text()='"&A1&"']]/div/div[@class='inj-container']"),"SELECT Col2,Col8")
```

- In this formula, the cells "A1" and "A2" are `Aston Villa` and `https://www.sportsgambler.com/injuries/football/england-premier-league/`, respectively.
- When I tested your formula, no values are returned. When I saw the HTML of the URL, `A1` of `h3[contains(@class,'"&A1&"')]` is in the text of the tag `a`. I think that by this, no values are returned.

#### Result:

[image]

#### References:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)
- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)